# How to replace a string with & and not &amp; in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I'm struggle with a PS script.

I call a script for a database connection, and I have a connection string like that :

```
$sample = "provider connection string=&quot;User Id=aa;Password=aa;Host=127.0.0.1;"
```

Then I write that in a file. Prob is the part

```
string=&quot;User
```

In the file, I finally have

```
string=&amp;quot;User
```

How can I keep my original string and not have
`&`
replaced with `&amp;` ?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: How you are writing into the file? Working fine for me with `Set-Content` Cmdlet.

Comment: Oh, it's a xml attribute, so I use XMLDocument.SetAttribute(), and then XMLDocument.save(), will try with Set-Content :D Thanks a lot